# What Function can I use to get the handle of a button?

Tags: c++, windows

the situation is as follows:

I have the handle for a window (which i got with the function FindWindowEx() ) and that window has 3 buttons. I would like to know how I can get the handle for 1 of the 3 buttons. I mean I know ppl can use spy++, but I am sure there have to be functions that can do it for me, so my questions are:

Question::
What function or functions can I use to get the handle of a button of a window (already knowing the handle for the window)?

Question2::
How do I get the Button's ID???

Comment: Use GetDlgItem().  You have to know the ID, use Spy++ to see it.

Comment: Hans, the thing is I tried to get it on spy++ and couldn't find how.... I mean i have visual studio 2010 and have used the spy++ to find the window... but wheree is the option for the button?? I have spent 2 days with the program and still nothing bro..

Comment: Take a step back. What are you trying to do with the button? Perhaps UI Automation will be a better approach.

Comment: I am trying to click a button on another program. I decided to use EnumChildWindows() to look through all the child windows until I hit a specific one which has the button I want to click... however... the problem is how do I identify the button? I mean the button needs some characteristic that makes it identifyable and i have tried to use spy++ to find something but I am a bit of a newby... I dont know what UI automation is... might be a good option, but I don't really want to enter a new library just yet and discard everything Ive done so far

Comment: But if you can explain to me how UI Automation works, I would appriciate it

Comment: This is a job for UI Automation. You can [look for the button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff625913(v=vs.85).aspx) say by name, then Invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through children of that window with [EnumChildWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It lets you define a callback function to be called for every child of the window.

In the callback, you can check if the current child is the button you need.

For example, if you dinamically want to press an OK button, you can check if the window text equals `OK`. You can get the window text with [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you know the position in the parent window you can use [ChildWindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
For this to work you will probably have to check the windows status first (maximazed or current width-height) to be sure the button is right where you want.

An easy way may also be getting his position relative to another child of the window that's easier to retrieve. For example, if the button is always to the right of a text-box control, you can get coordinates of the text-box and use `ChildWindowFromPoint` passing those coordinates with something added in the `x` direction.

Comment: YEAH thats kind of what i am trying to do, however the buttons that I will be looking through are actually icons... there are 3 icons, with no caption in them... so I am guessing I need to look at what special characteristic the one button I want to press has... but what characteristic could that be?

Comment: I found myself in a situation like this. The program I was trying to interact with didn't use regular buttons: they had custom-made graphics and functionalities. The only thing I could do to get the button was through their position in the parent. See updated answer.

Comment: Yeah. I also noticed recently that the fact that the buttons I am looking at currently are in the toolbar actually makes them like "toolbar buttons" and messages like BN_CLICK dont work. Instead you use the msgs with TB_ as the prefix. Slowly but surely I am moving forward :P